# Having xticks to display Months in a Seaborn regplot with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, label, seaborn

I can not figure how to make the xticks to display Months.

For a reproducible example, my data is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

json = '{"index":{"0":0,"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7,"8":8,"9":9,"10":10,"11":11,"12":12,"13":13,"14":14,"15":15,"16":16},"Date":{"0":1516147200000,"1":1516752000000,"2":1517788800000,"3":1520208000000,"4":1520985600000,"5":1522281600000,"6":1522886400000,"7":1523404800000,"8":1523491200000,"9":1524096000000,"10":1525305600000,"11":1525737600000,"12":1526428800000,"13":1527811200000,"14":1533686400000,"15":1534377600000,"16":1534809600000},"FB":{"0":0.978943931,"1":1.0282769543,"2":0.999118052,"3":0.994377665,"4":1.0152684601,"5":0.880773866,"6":0.8782934503,"7":0.91676777,"8":0.9032631287,"9":0.9265792518,"10":0.959210704,"11":0.9862198213,"12":1.0098114818,"13":1.0692867773,"14":1.0207253613,"15":0.962958874,"16":0.9514937543},"month":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":3,"5":3,"6":4,"7":4,"8":4,"9":4,"10":5,"11":5,"12":5,"13":6,"14":8,"15":8,"16":8}}'

toy_data = pd.read_json(json)
```

[image]

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('Share Price Facebook, Google and the SP500')
sns.regplot( x = 'index', y = 'FB', data = toy_data , label = 'FB', fit_reg = True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to ammend the code so that in the x axis appear the Months of the Range of Observations. That is the tick labels 0 and 1 would be replaced with 'Jan' (appearing once), the tick label 2 would be replaced with 'Feb', the tick labels 3, 4, 5 with 'March' (appearing once), etc.

Comment: When you post a code, make sure people can paste it and run it without any troubles. Your code is no good for that purpose

Comment: I think I would understand the question if `index` ranged between 1 and 12. But which month is 13?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  @ImportanceOfBeingErnest:  The datapoints represent days. In a real life situation there may be hundrends of them and displaying the exact date on the x axis is impossible.  So I would like to give an indication to the reader as of which month/year the paricular cluster of points refer to. Is that clear?  I can elaborate it on it if you want.

Comment: @Bazingaa : Sorry I had omitted to paste the text of the title.  Now it should run.

Comment: Well, the data in the question's code will not produce the plot shown. Although that might not matter for the purpose of the question it's sure confusing. I edited your post to contain a runnable code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your dates to numbers and use those numbers as the `x` input for the `regplot`. Then you can format your ticklabels as dates.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import seaborn as sns

json = '{"index":{"0":0,"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7,"8":8,"9":9,"10":10,"11":11,"12":12,"13":13,"14":14,"15":15,"16":16},"Date":{"0":1516147200000,"1":1516752000000,"2":1517788800000,"3":1520208000000,"4":1520985600000,"5":1522281600000,"6":1522886400000,"7":1523404800000,"8":1523491200000,"9":1524096000000,"10":1525305600000,"11":1525737600000,"12":1526428800000,"13":1527811200000,"14":1533686400000,"15":1534377600000,"16":1534809600000},"FB":{"0":0.978943931,"1":1.0282769543,"2":0.999118052,"3":0.994377665,"4":1.0152684601,"5":0.880773866,"6":0.8782934503,"7":0.91676777,"8":0.9032631287,"9":0.9265792518,"10":0.959210704,"11":0.9862198213,"12":1.0098114818,"13":1.0692867773,"14":1.0207253613,"15":0.962958874,"16":0.9514937543}}'
df = pd.read_json(json)
df["Date2"] = mdates.date2num(pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('Share Price Facebook, Google and the SP500')
sns.regplot( x = 'Date2', y = 'FB', data = df , label = 'FB', fit_reg = True, ax=ax)

loc = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to retain the graph I posted and simply replace the xtick labels?  I understand that there will not be a one to one relationship between x values and tick labels, but that is OK to me.

Comment: That's possible. But you need to decide (and tell people) by what you want to replace the labels.

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you for letting me know.  I apologize for any confusion I caused.  I edited my question to make more clear what I am driving at.